# Create an IF statement for a Variable to see if it contains a range of letters

Tags: jinja2

{% if val|first in 'ABCDEFG' %}

This works but doing it this way seems a little clumsy to me. Especially with the number of if statements I will be creating.

I've been searching for a solution for hours but can't quite find what I need. I imagine there is an option to help clean up my script.

Is there a way to make this something like: { if val|first in 'A-G' %} ?  Bonus points if you can help me make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the answer you are looking for.

```
{% if val|first|lower in 'a'-'g' %}
```

This will convert the first character of `val` to uppercase and check if it is within the range of A-G. You can make it case insensitive by converting it to either `upper` or `lower`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I tried what you suggested and I get the following error "
Error: template rendering failed. unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'"

Comment: This is what I came up with that works.  If anyone is aware of a way to 'clean' this up. It would be greatly appreciated.

{# Set ISE Server Order #}
{% set HN = hostname[0:2]%}
{% if (HN == "EO") or (HN == "SH") or (HN == "UP") or (HN == "PS") or (HN == "VE")%}

{% set ISE = "ISE1" %}
{% else %}
{% if HN|first|lower in 'abcdefg' %}
{% set ISE = "ISE2" %}
{% else %}
{% if HN|first|lower in 'hijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' %}
{% set ISE = "ISE3" %}
{% set ISE2 = "This" %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endif %}

Comment: `{% set values = set(["EO", "SH", "UP", "PS", "VE"]) %}
{% if HN in values %}
    {% set ISE = "ISE1" %}`

Something like this?